# Bold large values in a correlation matrix with huxtable

Tags: r, r-markdown

How do I bold values in a correlation matrix that are larger than the absolute value of, say, 0.3.  This is sort of where I am at.

`library(huxtable)
    var1<-rnorm(100)
    var2<-rnorm(100)
    var3<-rnorm(100)
    var4<-rnorm(100)
    df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4)
    library(tidyverse)
    df %>% 
    cor(.) %>% 
    huxtable() %>%
    map_bold(., by_ranges(0.2, 0.4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

`map_bold()` maps values to a property, breaks specifies where you want the new property to kick in and `values()` dictates what the property should be, in the sequences of the breaks. So, below -0.2, the bold property should be `TRUE`, above 0.2, it should be `FALSE` and then above 0.2 it should be `TRUE` again.

Also, by leaving the rows and cols arguments to map_bold empty, it applies to all rows and cols.

```
library(huxtable)
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-rnorm(100)
var3<-rnorm(100)
var4<-rnorm(100)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
cor(.) %>% 
huxtable() %>% 
map_bold(., 
by_ranges(breaks=c(-0.2, 0.2), values=c(T, F, T)))
```